# Exchange 2k7: external email in distribution group

Tags: email, exchange-2007, distribution-lists

We've got a distribution group configured which receives all email to *Notification.LiveMonitoring@example.com* and sends it to the appropriate developers. What I need to do is add an external email address to the list of recipients - eg Emails gets sent to all the existing internal accounts and some gmail ones too.

As I'm sure the question reveals, I know *very* little about exchange management - I'm sure this is quite simple but I don't seem to be able to figure it out.

Googling has resulted in ways to configure outlook to do this (no good - outlook might not be open). I suspect I'm using the wrong terms but again am unsure.

If someone would please point me at the right documentation, it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an external [mail contact](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997220%28EXCHG.80%29.aspx) using the exchange administration tools (examples for gui and command line in link), which can then be added to the DL as you would a normal contact.

As for terminology around this stuff, you may find [this](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/exchange2007/exchange2007_recipients.htm) useful too.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you - I'll go do some reading but it seems like exactly what I need.

Comment: Yep - took me about 30 seconds once I'd realised what I needed to do. Thank you. I'll mark as correct as soon as SF will let me

Comment: Happy to have helped. Exchange is one of those things that's very easy once you know what to do and largely impenetrable when you don't.